# WPF - Reload an a collection (with 'new') without rebinding controls

Tags: wpf, data-binding, collections

Imagine the following:

```
class Repository
{
    private ObservableCollection<ModelClass> _allEntries;
    public ObservableCollection<ModelClass> AllEntries
    {
        get { return _allEntries; }
        set { _allEntries = value; }
    }
    public void RefreshDataFromDB()
    {
        _all = new ObservableCollection(GetMyData()); // whatever method there is
    }
}
```

Now there are a couple of controls that bind to this collection, e.g.:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Repository.AllEntries, ElementName=Whatever}"/>
```

The problem now is that if I call the `RefreshDataFromDB` the bindings get lost (at least it seems so) as the _all is now pointing to new memory part and the bindings still use the old reference. `INotifyPropertyChanged` does not help me in this case (e.g. putting it in `RefreshDataFromDB` does not help a lot).

The question would be - how would you handle a case where you replce a collection and want to update its consumers' bindings?

Comment: I think there is some typo mistake, your property name is AllEntries whereas you are binding to ALL!

Comment: What exactly you mean by :

"the bindings get lost (at least it seems so)"

Can you please provide some more details.

Comment: The question had a simple solution, yet just to clarify:
1. Yes, it is a typo there. It should be AllEntries.
2. Bindings get lost a they are initially bound to the variable _all => some memory reference. When I use the 'new' keyword the _all reference changes and points to another address in memory but the controls that bind to _all are still looking at the old memory. Basically the problem was how to avoid controls using the old address. That's it.

The simple solution by Kieren (.Clear() + .AddRange()) helped my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; you're not modifying the collection, the UI is bound to the collection, and then you replace it with a new one.

You could do this:

```
_all.Clear();
_all.AddRange(GetMyData());
```

Hope that helps!

---

Alternatively, make AllEntries (or All.. your nomenclature seems to change a few times on the post ;)) a DependencyProperty:

```
public static DependencyProperty AllEntriesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AllEntries", typeof(ObservableCollection), typeof(MyClass));
```

You'd need to make the get/set property too, see here for an example:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx

Comment: You don't necessarily need a `DependencyProperty` - `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation on the property is enough.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. I didn't think of just clearing the same instance in the first place :)